# Auto start and stop water AC motor using these two circuits

Tags: hacking

Problem: 
    I have a AC motor (pump) which pumps water from the      ground floor to 4th floor. On 4th floor, I have water tank. The problem is I have to start the motor in 5AM in morning. I have installed a water alarm buzzer which beeps when tank is full. I want to automate this using some circuits.

Solution: Automatic solution which will start motor at 5AM daily in morning. There is no automatic turn off (based on time). Motor will stop automatically when water tank is full.

I have purchased Two items

1. Daily Weekly Programmable Electronic Switch.
   http://www.ebay.in/itm/Daily-Weekly-Programmable-Electronic-Timer-Switch-220V-AC-16A-MCB-Digital-Relay-/191748990517
2. Water Level Controller.
   http://www.ebay.in/itm/Water-Level-Controller-Tank-Level-Controller-Works-On-12VDC-AC-/111819716037

There first device has capability to turn on motor at scheduled time. The second circuit behave differently. Second circuit start motor when water is below certain level and automatic switch off when it certain level.

Can i use these two device and create something which I want ?

May be I need to purchase some more circuit/devices. Please help to guide to make this hack.

final thought : I want, my AC motor pump to auto start at 5 AM in morning and automatic switch off when it full.

I do not need     any     other kind of logic that if Water is below at certain level then auto start motor. Because, there is no use to start even if water is below certain level because in my area water supply happens only for 4AM to 6AM.

I am software guy and understand basic  electronics. Solution like have a Pi board or use GSM kind of things will not be helpful, because I want a minimum solution for my problem and not a fancy luxury solution like (app controlled switch etc).

I searched a lot on Internet and found these two cheapest circuits which can help me.
Let me know if you know any other cheaper way to achieve my goal.
I have purchased first device in $13 and I am going to buy second circuit in $4.

Thanks
========== Update 1========
After reading answers, and with my limited understanding on electronics, I have created this circuit picture !

Let me know If I want need to add extra resistors or this circuit will blow my house !

Image attached here.
[image: a busy cat]

Comment: I have uploaded image at http://postimg.org/image/smsm0yidv/ Let me know if this is not a suitable way to show image here !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wire outputs from each module in series, so you'll get the AND function. Thepump will start if the time is in the interval AND if water level is below AND not at higher level. You should use this signal to control a contactor (not directly as depicted) and you put a circuit braker for pump, yet better to use motor protection switch. But this isn't a very stable solution. Better would be using floating switches - it's a switch that is anchored in the tank, when water level falls (or rises) the float switch is inclinated so it switvhes the contact. With latching float switches with relays you can obtain a simple and durable solution.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJN6mR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1K3Te.png)</sup>

Comment: You are basically saying that, I do not need second circuit (Water level controller). Instead, I should buy - http://www.ebay.in/itm/12V-1-Channel-Relay-Board-for-Arduino-Raspberry-Pi-AVR-PIC-ARM-8051-CH-/301676752419 !

Comment: I think, Circuit can be simplified if we do not included "LOW" water signal. I do not need low water signal.

Comment: Yes you need it, otherwise the pump will turn on/off without hysteresis. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Float_switch - those are two switches, and RLY1 is a contactor with auxiliary contacts.

Comment: I do not have Float Switch !! I have simple two wires . These two wires going in Water tank - Like this - http://www.ebay.in/itm/Contact-type-sensor-for-water-level-controller-or-indicator-Single-Pair-Sensor-/252173172425 ! Water goes up, circuit is completed.

Comment: Have you at least read my answer?

Comment: My understanding is limited ! I have created a circuit diagram. Let me know if this will help or do i need to put extra resistors ? Unable to find option to attach image , so Adding image in new answer !

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got your answer 100%. It is much more clear now. May you please review my diagram as well ?

Comment: I did the new one that shall suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

The float switch is normally closed when the tank isn't topped off, and the timer can then energize the contactor, filling the tank.

Then when the tank gets full, the float switch will open, de-energizing the contactor and stopping the pump.

I'm pretty sure you won't be able to get the relay to work using the water and wires as a switch, plus there's the danger of evolving hydrogen and oxygen from the water via electrolysis, so I'd go for a nice float switch and not have to worry about any of that.

There are some nice, cheap ones on Ebay India.

[image]

Comment: Hi @EM Fields,
may you check the image, which I have uploaded.

Comment: @NarendraSisodiya: Part 1.) OK, thanks, I did. It looks like you're planning to use the timer and a relay to control the pump, with the relay being actuated by a 1.5 volt cell and the change in resistance between two electrodes as water comes between them.   That's a very, very, bad idea from the point of view that there's no guarantee the relay will work with that kind of resistance in series with, and that low a voltage used to energize its coil.

Comment: @NarendraSisodiya: Part 2.)  But even worse than that, even if it does work, there must be constant current into the coil to keep the pump OFF, and there'll  be metal ions dissolved into the electrolyte - the water in the tank - which you must surely use as potable.  A better idea, which would keep the water as clean as it was when it entered the tank would be to use a mechanical float switch attached to the side of the tank which opens when the tank is full and, through a relay with an AC coil (as shown in my sketch) controls the motor during its  "fill" stage.

Comment: @NarendraSisodiya: Part 3.) if you're afraid of high voltages at the tank, then you could interpose a transformer between the timer's output and the  tank's contactor and use that lower voltage to run the pump motor contactor'

Comment: 1. I will use a 12V source in circuit. So relay will be actuated by 12V and not 1.5V.  I do not know, I should place a resistor or not.

2. "constant current into the coil to keep the pump OFF". This is not a case ! In my diagram, I am connected wire to "NC" terminal. During whole day, waster tank is 100% full for only 30 minutes. So, wires in tank which complete circuit will actually work only for 30 minutes. That means, I do not need constant current to keep my pump off. Yes, I need a constant current ( from 12V source) to keep my pump off.

Comment: Here is the flow.
1) normally tank is below 100% full point where i placed my wires. So there is no current. Relay will be Normally connected mode. and that will complete the timer circuit.
2) When timer is ON, motor will start.
3) At one point, tank will be full 100% and that will complete the relay circuit and relay will be activated. on activated, this will close the circuit which is going to motor and thus , motor will be turned off !